# Java Array family program

Tags: java, arrays

Need help, I need to design a program to read in a sequence of
how many children there are per family for a group of families.

The code should accomplish the following:

- store number of children in an array,
- calculate the average number of children per family, and
- report how many families have an above average number of children.

Also, I need to add a second loop to find out how many families have less than the average number of children.

I am allowed to declare and initialize variables as needed, here is what I have so far:

```
int numFamilies;

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("For how many families will a child count be entered?");
numFamilies = scan.nextInt();

// create the array
int[] numChildren = new int[numFamilies];

 // read in the number of children for each family and find the average
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print ("Enter number of children for family " + (i+1) +": ");
    numChildren[i] = scan.nextInt();

}
// loop to find out how many families have less than the average
// number of children
```

Comment: For how many families would the user be entering data? Also, what number of children is considered above or below average?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please read this:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question to understand why.

Comment: As far as the number of families the values are read in from the user using the scanner so it could be any number entered.  I was planning on using 2 for the average number of children.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java8 or higher you can use `java.util.Arrays`([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)) class:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(numChildren).sum();
```

If not you can iterate the array:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int children : numChildren) {
    sum += children;
}
```

For the average:

```
int average = numFamilies / sum;
```

Finally you can then iterate over the array and check your criteria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren.length; i++) {
    String result = numChildren[i] >= sum ? "above or equal to" : "less than";
    System.out.println("Family: " + (i+1) + " is " + result + " the average";
}
```

**Notes:**

1. You need to add additional checks for division by zero etc
2. You could use `Double` for better precision